# STM32 array to control individual GPIO

Tags: c, arrays, stm32, gpio

I'm new to embedded systems and C programming. I am currently trying to program a PCB using an STM32 microcontroller to control an array of 8 fans upon receipt of a single commenad. i.e 00001011 will switch on fans 5, 7 and 8. There are a total of 256 possible combinations and it wouldn't be very efficient to program each individual one.

I am thinking of using an array to achieve this using something like;

```
fan_array[8] = {fan1, fan2, fan3, fan4, fan5, fan6, fan7, fan8};
printf ("Input fan state"); // user would input binary number as shown above
scanf (%d, fan_array);
```

Would this set the GPIO pins controlling each fan high or low according to the binary values input into the array?

Comment: Do the STM32 have the GPIO port directly addressable? You could make `fan_array` a pointer and make it point to that address.

Comment: Hi, looking at the memory map it looks like the GPIO's are directly addressble. Thanks! I'll have to look into making the array a pointer

Comment: 7 fans are connected into port B and 1 fan is connected to port A. The reason for this was ease of routing tracks on the PCB

Comment: I think you need to learn C first and then start microcontrollers programming. uC programming requires very good knowledge of the programing language.

Comment: So for example if i wanted fan 8 on which corresponds to PB2 I could do something like: GPIOB->ODR = 0x0002. Which would set Port B pin 2 high?

Comment: @P__J__ True, thanks. I should have read a bit closer. I deleted my comment.

Comment: @cath001 it will set the PB1 not 2. And it will also reset all others. As I wrorte before - it is much too early for you - learn the basics first. Master bits, bit manipulations, learn how to set,reset or toggle particular bits in the number etc etc then start programming uCs.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, there are 256 possible combinations, but you're only interested in 8 fans, so all that you need to check is 8 bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STATE_ON    0x01
#define STATE_OFF    0x00

void enable_relay(unsigned char relay, unsigned char state)
{
    /* This is a brute force approach that enables any relay/port combination:
     * relay 8: PB2
     * relay 7: PB4
     * (...)
     * relay 1: PA1
     */

    switch(relay)
    {
        case 8:
            if(state == STATE_ON)
                GPIOB->ODR |= 0x0004;
            else
                GPIOB->ODR &= ~0x0004;
            break;
        case 7:
            if(state == STATE_ON)
                GPIOB->ODR |= 0x0010;
            else
                GPIOB->ODR &= ~0x0010;
            break;
        case 1:
            if(state == STATE_ON)
                GPIOA->ODR |= 0x0002;
            else
                GPIOA->ODR &= ~0x0002;
            break;
    }

}

void check_relay(unsigned char fan_map)
{
int i;
unsigned char bit;
unsigned char state;

    for(i=0; i < 8; i++) {
        bit = (fan_map&(0x01<<i));
        state = ((bit != 0)? STATE_ON : STATE_OFF);
        enable_relay( (8-i), state);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char fan_map = 0x0B; /* 0x0B = 00001011 */
    check_relay(fan_map);
}
```

You need the `8-i` part as your bit order is in reverse (fan1 as the leftmost bit) with the value order (MSB is the leftmost bit).